# Having trouble calling Oracle stored procedure in java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, ora-06550

I'm having trouble calling an Oracle stored procedure in Java. I added a stored procedure to the database like this:

```
         String SQL = "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVERESULTS() " +
                    "IS " +
                    "BEGIN" +
                            " SELECT POOL_ID, POOL_MBR_ID, BSLN_CD, PGE_TYP_NM, SERV_NM, CL_FILE_NM" +
                            " FROM LBMADM.TPPO_MSTR_MAP " +
                            " ORDER BY SERV_NM" +
                            " WHERE PGE_TYP_NM = 'live' ; " +
                    "END";

                    stmtLIVE = con.createStatement();
                    stmtLIVE.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

And now I'm trying to call it like this :

```
CallableStatement cs;

                 try {
                         cs = con.prepareCall("{call LIVERESULTS() }");
                         rs = cs.executeQuery();

                         while (rs.next()) {
 .....
```

However, I'm getting the following errors:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
 PLS-00905: object UT9J.GENERATE_SQL_FOR_LIVE is invalid
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong. I read Oracle's documentation on it and I believe I did everything right, but I guess not. If anyone can shed some light on the situation I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You create proc `LIVE` and call `LIVERESULTS`

Comment: @JustYo: no the error is pretty specific (and OP should google ORA-nnn to see what it is).  It is a general *syntax* error and indicates ORA never even got to calling the wrong proc.  It can NOT generate the necessary SQL for "live()" -- e.g. PLS-00905 -- because "LINE 1" of the procedure def is missing required IS keyword (e.g. Syntax error ORA-06550).

Comment: I actually had IS in there, along with the correct match of LIVERESULTS (I copied it over wrong). I have googled it but I'm still a bit stuck.

Comment: You also have the ORDER BY before the WHERE clause.  See Rajesh's response below.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the procedure? Even if you fix it so that you're putting the results of the select statement into a variable, you're still not accomplishing anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple issues here..

1) Why do you want to create the procedure inside Java Code? You should create it directly in Oracle using SQLPLUS or any other Database tool.

2) Oracle does not expect () when there are no in/out/in-out parameters, so you don't need them. You also need as "as" or "is" keyword after the "create or replace procedure". Otherwise, This will give the compile time error that you are seeing..

```
  1  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVE
  2  IS
  3  begin
  4    null;   ---This would usually have your logic, 
               --Null indicates "DO nothing". Just to concentrate on 
               --the "declare" issues
  5* end;
SQL> /

Procedure created.
```

3) The third error is that you are selecting fields from a table, but there are no varibles "INTO" which you are selecting them.

```
  1  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVE
  2  AS
  3    v_ename scott.emp.ename%type;
  4  begin
  5    select ename
  6      from scott.emp
  7      where empno = 7369;
  8* end;
SQL> /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE LIVE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/3      PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

  1  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVE
  2  AS
  3    v_ename scott.emp.ename%type;
  4  begin
  5    select ename
  6      into v_ename
  7      from scott.emp
  8      where empno = 7369;
  9* end;
SQL> /

Procedure created.
```

4) You are creating a procedure called "LIVE" and calling "LIVERESULTS".Again, you don't need () after the Procedure call.

5) Based on Allan's comments below and Cybernate's answer(+1), if you are trying to return a result set, you should open a refcursor for your select and then return it to the calling program.

Comment: I actually had the correct match between prodcure names and the addition of IS- I had a bad C/P. The problem is that I don't have any tools to directly access the DB from my machine- this is a workaround. How would I properly address your third point?

Comment: 1. You should be able to do download SQLPLUS from Oracle or Oracle's free tool "SQL Developer" to use as a development tool. Creating them from Java just isn't right. Also, there is every chance that your "J2USER" (or any other Java user that you login with ) might not have the "create PROCEDURE" privilege in a higher environment. (well.. they shouldn't be able to do that even in development environment..)

Comment: It would be worth pointing out that the function provided effectively does nothing. It might as well be `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVE AS begin null; end;`

Comment: @Allan -updated my post, Thanks.! I intentionally put in NULL, to show the error in the Procedure declaration clearly.

Comment: I actually meant the last version of the procedure with the `select...into`. Unless something is done with the resulting record, the select is pointless.

Answer (score 4):

The stored procedure `LIVE` will not be compiled without errors, since you have a SELECT STATEMENT without INTO clause in an SP which is not valid.

Hence the issue. Use a REF CURSOR to return the result set.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, which are all good ...

You're probably expecting that since the `CREATE PROCEDURE` does not raise a SQLException, the procedure is compiled successfully.  But this just indicates that it succeeded as a SQL statement -- i.e. a procedure was created.  The procedure then has to be compiled as PL/SQL code, and that is failing due to various syntax errors that have been pointed out by others.  In this situation, the procedure is created, so the SQL succeeds, but it has errors and is invalid.

An Oracle-specific tool, like SQL*Plus, is aware of this and displays appropriate feedback ("Procedure created with compilation errors") as shown in Rajesh's answer.  JDBC doesn't check this automatically.  If you really need to do the creation from Java, you should immediately check for errors after executing the `CREATE`:  `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE NAME='LIVERESULTS'`.  This will return essentially the same information that is displayed by the SQL*Plus `SHOW ERRORS` command.

You need to resolve the PL/SQL compilation errors before you can call the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

[You are missing the [required] `IS` (or alternatively 'AS')](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/img_text/create_procedure.htm).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVE() 
IS 
BEGIN
   <the body here> 
END;
```

[edit]